# Is SEPA Instant Credit Transfer (SCT Inst) a replacement for "classic" SEPA transfers or just for special purposes?

Tags: international-transfer, sepa

Is SEPA Instant Credit Transfer (SCT Inst) a dropin replacement for classic SEPA transfers? Or is it something that is/will be available under special conditions?

In other words, if I transfer 100 EUR to my parents today, it takes a few hours or days, can I expect, that the same thing will be instant (up to 10 seconds, per standard) the next year(assuming both banks implement SCTI by then)? Using the same bank accounts. (I am not asking about a possible extra fees charged by any of the involved banks, but if SCTI is/will cover such a scenario)